# Jar file executes but can't access database.sqlite , database is being created without tables

Tags: java, database, sqlite, executable-jar

**NOT A DUPLICATE**

I am using `firefox SQLite manager` and I created one *database.sqlite* file which I put into my project directory *before src directory*. When I compile code from `IDE, it can access` the database since it has tables but When I execute JAR file of my project . It creates a new database.sqlite exactly in same directory where my JAR is, But when opened it has no table, nothing. And thus my application doesn't even start(login doesn't work).

Can't figure out how to solve that!
Also some threads say, one can't update SQLite database that resides in JAR file. In my case it is created as soon as I double click on Jar file. So dO I need to change anything?And how to solve that no table problem mentioned above?Thank you.

I did some changes like suggested on previous threads but none of them helped !

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite::resource:database.sqlite");
```

Comment: A embedded resource may not be loadable by the jdbc driver, it certainly won't be writable

Comment: @MadProgrammer then how do i use my sqlite file? I want database in my application and application is supposed to be JAR

Comment: I runs when i keep my good .sqlite file in the folder where jar is..but i want it to be created automatically

Comment: You can use `Class#getAsResource` to get a URL reference to the embedded resource, you can try using that as part of the connection path or extract the database to a known location